# Twisted Python - twistd - How to remove old log files

Tags: python, logging, twisted, twistd

I am using `twistd` to run my application, and I read [how to customize the logger](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html#customizing-twistd-logging).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the default logger (`-l` option, uses sequential integers for extensions) or the `DailyLogFile` to limit the number of rotated logs.  I'd ideally like the rotated log files to have date extensions in "%Y-%m-%d" format and be limited to 7 at a time.

I tried using `logrotate` on my system, but I found that it inexplicably puts binary data in the log file when it does a `copytruncate`.

EDIT: I believe the reason for the binary data may be similar to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/71348/55749).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the default logger, you can specify `maxRotatedFiles` which will limit the number of files created. See this answer for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/32273153/66349

The `DailyLogFile` class doesn't support this option. There is a [patch](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/attachment/ticket/7842/daily-log-file-max-rotated-files-7842-1.patch) to add the functionality but I believe (from memory) it hasn't been accepted yet as it's missing a few tests and/or doesn't meet some code style guidelines.

Also note that twisted changed their logging system recently so this is all considered legacy now. It still works but that may change at some point. Here's a link to the new `twisted.logger` docs https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/howto/logger.html